# Unable to connect to the 5 GHz band

Tags: wireless, network-manager

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. I have recently got a dual-band router. But the wifi selection menu does not show me the option to connect to the 5 GHz band. However, I am able to connect to the 2.4 GHz signal. I am new to Ubuntu and I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: The router is 5GHz capable, but is your computer's Wireless NIC 5GHz capable?

Comment: Yes, it is capable

Comment: Have you configured the router to have 5GHz turned on, and specified a different SSID (Network Name)?

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`.